# Allowing user to install an app via an ad in another app

Tags: ios, ads, in-app

I am building a third party library that is essentially an ad network, i.e., it will provide ads in apps. So, I need to allow users to install apps from within the app, using an ad - something like Facebook, where you see an app advertisement, you click that ad and install it - all within Facebook.

So I need to way to let users install those apps without leaving the app in which the ad is shown. Another recent example of this is [Appsfire](http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/22/with-new-developer-toolkit-appsfire-wants-to-kill-crappy-banner-ads-on-mobile/). They allow users to tap on ads, install those apps and return to Appsfire (essentially not letting the user leave).

I tried searching for an AppStore API but all I could find is the API to query AppStore, not a way to display an app and let users install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [**`SKStoreProductViewController`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html) - which looks like this:

[image]

<sup>It works for apps, songs, books - anything on the iTunes store. Image credit [techotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image:Iphone_ios_6_skstoreproductview_book.png).</sup>

[This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class) is a good tutorial on the subject - usage comes down to:

- Importing the `StoreKit` framework,
- Creating an instance of the view controller,
- Assigning a delegate,
- Telling it what to display,
- Presenting it,
- And implementing the delegate methods

Which comes down to this code:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
storeViewController.delegate = self;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:<item id>]};
[storeViewController loadProductWithParameters:parameters 
             completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
            if (result)
                [self presentViewController:storeViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
}];
```

You can get your iTunes product ID using [iTunes' LinkMaker](http://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/). The ID is also shown under the Manage your Apps section of iTunes Connect:

[image]

The one required delegate method is a simple dismissal action:

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```